# Function similar to head() in Matlab

Tags: arrays, r, matlab

I'm simply trying to find out if there in `Matlab` is a simple equivalent to `head()` in `R`? It should display/print the top 5 rows of an array. So given the following `table`

```
var1 = transpose(1:6);
var2 = transpose(2:7);
aa = table(var1,var2);
```

I am looking for a funtion `xx` that produces the same as:

```
aa(1:5,:)
```

ans =

```
var1    var2
____    ____

1       2   
2       3   
3       4   
4       5   
5       6
```

something like:

```
xx(aa)
```

I could of course keep using the indexes above, but it would be more convenient with a function. I have used `head()` extensively in `R`.

Comment: Why not just write it yourself? It sounds like something you'd use for prototyping so it shouldn't be an issue if it's local to only your computer. Write your own and add it your path...

Comment: Exactly, I was writting hte same. It looks trivial to create. Its just a dunction with a line of code, just write it!

Comment: Yes, that is true. I guess it doesn't exists then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the top few rows, then just type `mydata[1:5,]` .

I use the following toy, from a certain someone's :-)  `cgwtools` package, which allows you to specify how many items to display and has an option to skip a few elements if desired. As it happens, I chose not to retain dimensions, to make it easier to examine a `list` object.  Feel free to take this code & modify to your needs (e.g. remove the part which returns the last `numel` elements if you only want the "head" of your data).

```
short <-function (x = seq(1, 20), numel = 4, skipel = 0, ynam = deparse(substitute(x))) 
{
    ynam <- as.character(ynam)
    ynam <- gsub(" ", "", ynam)
    if (is.list(x)) 
        x <- unlist(t(x))
    if (2 * numel >= length(x)) {
        print(x)
    }
    else {
        frist = 1 + skipel
        last = numel + skipel
        cat(paste(ynam, "[", frist, "] thru ", ynam, "[", last, 
            "]\n", sep = ""))
        print(x[frist:last])
        cat(" ... \n")
        cat(paste(ynam, "[", length(x) - numel - skipel + 1, 
            "] thru ", ynam, "[", length(x) - skipel, "]\n", 
            sep = ""))
        print(x[(length(x) - numel - skipel + 1):(length(x) - 
            skipel)])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is two functions equivalent to head() and tail() in R. You can just copy/paste the source code into an .m file and save it in your desired directory:

```
function head(data, varargin)
%head - displays the first n rows of an array
%
% Syntax:  head(data, n)
%
% Inputs:
%    data - data to display (table, double)
%    n - number of rows (integer, optional input)
%
% Author: Daniel A. Brodén
% KTH, Royal Institute of Technology, Osquldas Väg 10, 100 44, Stockholm
% email: danbro@kth.se
% Website: http://www.kth.se/profile/danbro
% August 2015; Last revision: Aug-2015
% Define parser object
p = inputParser;

% Required inputs
addRequired(p, 'data')

% Default values
default_n = 10;                                 

% Optional inputs
checkInt = @(x) validateattributes(x,{'numeric'},{'integer','positive'});
addOptional(p, 'n', default_n, checkInt)

% Parse inputs
parse(p, data, varargin{:})

% Conditions
if size(p.Results.data, 1) < p.Results.n
    error('Not enough rows')
end

% Return
data(1:p.Results.n,:)
end
```

Code for tail

```
function tail(data, varargin)
%tail - displays the last n rows of an array
%
% Syntax:  tail(data, n)
%
% Inputs:
%    data - data to display (table, double)
%    n - number of rows (integer, optional input)
%
% Author: Daniel A. Brodén
% KTH, Royal Institute of Technology, Osquldas Väg 10, 100 44, Stockholm
% email: danbro@kth.se
% Website: http://www.kth.se/profile/danbro
% August 2015; Last revision: Aug-2015

% Parser object
p = inputParser;

% Required inputs
addRequired(p, 'data')

% Default values
default_n = 10;

% Optional inputs
checkInt = @(x) validateattributes(x,{'numeric'},{'integer','positive'});
addOptional(p, 'n', default_n, checkInt)

% Parse inputs
parse(p, data, varargin{:})

% Conditions
if size(p.Results.data, 1) < p.Results.n
    error('Not enough rows')
end

% Return
data((size(data,1)-p.Results.n + 1):size(data,1),:)
end
```

Comment: why did you not pass `flipud(data)` to `head` in order to get the `tail` function?

Comment: I guess one can use the flipud() function too. The advantage here is that the head() and tail() functions are independent of each other.

Comment: but if you update any of the checks in one you have to do the other too...

Comment: you have an extra "end" at the end of "head".

Answer (score 0):

You can just write:

```
aa(1:min(5, end), :)
```

Or make a function that does the same